# Django array field filter

Tags: python, jquery, django, django-orm

In my case **customer** filed are array filed

```
customer = ArrayField(models.TextField(),default=[])
```

my model look like

| id | customer |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `{1,2,3}` |
| 2 | `{4,2,5}` |
| 3 | `{1,8,9}` |

i want to filter my model by `{5,8}`
output will be `2th ,3th` row

Comment: See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#contained-by 
and try `Object.objects.filter(customer__contained_by=[5, 8])`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [overlap](http://Post.objects.filter(tags__overlap=%5B%27thoughts%27%5D)) like this:

```
customer_ids = MyModel.objects.filter(
     customer__overlap=[5, 8]
).values_list('id', flat=True)
# do something with customer_ids
```

But using id to determine row number is not right because if you delete an item having an id as 3 and then after that insert a new item then that new item will be given an id of 4. So row number of last row will give you 4th row which is wrong.

You can get row number like this:

```
row_numbers = [index for index, customer_id in enumerate(customer_ids)]
```